# Show message when IF is not satisfied

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I am brand new to PHP, and am creating a page with job postings separated by category. I would like for a message "Sorry, there are currently no openings in this division." to display under the category if there are no jobs in the database that match that category. 
Each row in the table will have some category assigned, so the code I have written checks for the value and puts the associated information in the div.  IE - retail jobs go into Div id="retail". Wholesale jobs go into div id="wholesale"

I have written the following code but it doesn't work.

There are jobs in the table with the jobcat Retail, but the Sorry message appears 3 times underneath the first record returned, outside of a div with the class "job-details"

There are no jobs in the next category in the table, and with this code the "Sorry" message repeats 5 times.

Can anyone help me achieve what I am trying to do please?  I have not found any similar questions where an echo is repeating like this but I may not be using the right search terms.

The code below repeats 4 times on my page, with different categories for jobcat.

```
         <div id="retail"><h2>Retail</h2>
           <?php do { 
                 if ($row_info['jobcat'] == 'Retail'){
                     echo "<div class='job-post'>"; 
                     echo "<p><span class='header'>Position: </span>".$row_info['jobtitle'] . "</p>";
                     echo "<p><span class='header'>Location: </span>".$row_info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
                     echo "<p class='view-job'>View Details</p> <div class='job-details'>".nl2br($row_info['jobdesc']) ." <a href='job-application.php?id=".$row_info['id']."'>Apply</a></div>"; 
                     echo "</div>";
                    }  else{
                        echo "<p>Sorry, there are currently no openings in this division.</p>";
                        }
                  } while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info));
                     mysql_data_seek($info, 0);
                    $row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);
                    ?>
         </div>
```

I tried modifying based on the answer below to check for the value rather than empty, and this isn't working either - surely its poor implementation on my part but wanted to show anyway.  With this code, the first category pulls in the correct data, but the Sorry message shows for all other categories, even if there is a match in the table:

```
           <?php 
               if ($row_info['jobcat'] == 'Retail')
               {
                  while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
                     echo "<div class='job-post'>"; 
                                     echo "<p><span class='header'>Position: </span>".$row_info['jobtitle'] . "</p>";
                                     echo "<p><span class='header'>Location: </span>".$row_info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
                                     echo "<p class='view-job'>View Details</p> <div class='job-details'>".nl2br($row_info['jobdesc']) ."<a href='job-application.php?id=".$row_info['id']."'>Apply</a></div>"; 
                                     echo "</div>";
                  }

               }
               else
               {
                  echo "Sorry, there are no open positions at this time.";
               }
               mysql_data_seek($info, 0);
                $row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);
            ?>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question - See how you keep putting a closing php tag (`?>`) followed immediately by an opening php tag (`<?php`)? You should be able to see that this is completely unnecessary

Comment: You should provide the smallest (non-)working example, nobody wants to go through this code.

Comment: @zdhickman, yes I figured as much but Dreamweaver keeps putting them in and my "tutor" told me to leave them, they're fine. I was going to experiment with cleaning them up once I have this project resolved. Thank you.

Comment: @KamikazeCZ - i took away the repeating div, hope that helps.

Comment: This is awful, I wouldn't use Dreamweaver.

Comment: Dreamweaver writes lousy PHP.

Comment: your best friend when learning to program is a plain old text editor. that way you'll know for sure everything that's going on, because nothing will happen unless you make it happen.

Comment: Dreamweaver screws everything up, period. I'd rather use Notepad on Windows 2.0!

Comment: @sgroves ...Or the OP could install Eclipse... and he would no longer be worried about his code not working! :)

Comment: i completely agree. my boss has been trying to get me to use Dreamweaver for a year and I finally got a trial version. I will not be continuing.  Thank you for confirming my Dreamweaver doubts.

Comment: Your "tutor" should also know better than to use plain ol' MySQL. You should be using MySQLi with Prepared Statements. If you're going to learn, do it right first time.

Comment: if you're on windows, try notepad++. on mac, try textwrangler.

Comment: I use notepad for all my other development...sheesh I feel like I should just throw this project in the trash and start over. :/

Comment: you probably don't need to start over. reworking your code might help you learn something, in fact.

Comment: your loop's backwards. you don't fetch a row until AFTER the first iteration, so you'll be trying to output undefined $row values that first time around. the standard dB fetch loop is `while($row = ...) { do stuff }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a flag if the error condition arises, and then output an error after the loop (not inside it).

```
<?php
    $flag = false;

    do {
        if ($row_info['jobcat'] == 'Wholesale') {
            echo "<div class='job-post'>"; 
            echo "<p><span class='header'>Position: </span>".$row_info['jobtitle'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p><span class='header'>Location: </span>".$row_info['joblocation'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p class='view-job'>View Details</p> <div class='job-details'>".nl2br($row_info['jobdesc']) ."<a href='job-application.php?id=".$row_info['id']."'>Apply</a></div>"; 
            echo "</div>";
        } else{
            $flag = true;
        }
    } while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)); 

    mysql_data_seek($info, 0);
    $row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info);

    if ($flag) {
        echo "<p>Sorry, there are currently no openings in this division.</p>"
    }
?>
```

Comment: this worked for me, I was not able to implement @Revent's response with my limited php knowledge. I will revisit this once I get a book.

Comment: wait, this worked for you? this will always set `$flag` to `true`, which is NOT what you want. `$row_info['jobcat']` will never exist (let alone be equivalent to `'Wholesale'`) during the first iteration of the loop. see my answer for a solution that's a) correct and b) easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to not use a do/while loop for one, and secondly, your error message display for every iteration of the loop. Check the data first, and then loop through it if it's not empty

```
<?php 
   if (!empty($info))
   {
      while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
         // display data
      }

   }
   else
   {
      // error message here
   }
?>
```

You should also use mysqli_, not mysql_ functions because they are deprecated. I also strongly suggest getting an introduction to programming PHP book.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely be getting a book and hope to take an actual class.  My code needs to check the value of a field, and display something different depending on the value. The row will never be empty.  It will either have a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4, and I need to send the data to the associated div depending on the value.

Comment: I tried a version of your code (since the row will never be empty I don't think it is right for me as-is) but it did not work. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a very generalized answer, @sgroves answer is more specific so probably more helpful. But honestly I think there are better ways to do a category breakdown, starting with how you are getting your data and what you are doing with it in PHP. I generally use associative arrays for this type of project and set it up in such a way that it is very easy to loop through and display.

Comment: this isn't only a very generalized answer, it does **not** answer the question asked and will not solve the asker's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#assume there are no openings until we know otherwise
$openings_available = false;

while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
    if ($row_info['jobcat'] == 'Wholesale') {
        #echo statements here

        $openings_available = true;    #now we know there's at least one opening
    }
}

if (!$openings_available) {
    echo "<p>Sorry, there are currently no openings in this division.</p>";
}
```

Or, if you don't want to re-set `$openings_available` every time you have a `jobcat`, you could do this:

```
#assume there ARE openings until we encounter a row without a 'jobcat'
$openings_available = true;

while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)) {
    if ($row_info['jobcat'] == 'Wholesale') {
        #echo statements here
    } else {
        $openings_available = false;
    }
}

if (!$openings_available) {
    echo "<p>Sorry, there are currently no openings in this division.</p>";
}
```

I find this harder to understand, though.